# Writing dictionary addition function in R

Tags: python, r, json, cdsw

I need to write the equivalent of the following code in R but I'm not quite sure how to go about it:

```
def add(args):
  result = args["a"] + args["b"]
  return result
```

The reason why is because for the platform I am using (Cloudera Data Science Workbench) models need a JSON input to be able to call them using an API key

So if I write a test model in R such as:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    return (x + y)
}
```

I cannot do a call like {"x" : 2, "y" : 4} using the `httr` package.

So I either need to make a dictionary like call for functions in R

OR

I am simply calling JSON incorrectly in which case could someone help me format that correctly for an API call

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to create the character string  `{"x" : 2, "y" : 4}`? Do you have a named list e.g. `list(x = 2, y = 4)`?

Comment: @danlooo yes that would be ideal. It's frustrating that the API call needs to be in JSON format so every function needs to be a python dictionary type or R list type. No named list I just want to deploy a simple addition function and call it then in R using the API key using `httr::POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @danlooo for the help. Along with my own research I came up with an answer that satisfies my question

As the rest API needs a key-value pair format on CSDW, I can do the following taken from @danlooos answer:

```
f <- function(l) {
    return (l$a + l$b)
}

f(list(a = 2, b = 3) # Returns 5
```

This can be put into JSON format then for the API call as:

`{"a" : 2, "b" : 3}`

Answer (score 1):

JSON is the default data format for most REST APIs. We can serialize an R list to JSON using the `jsonlite` package. The other way of creating an R list based on a json string is also possible:

```r
library(jsonlite)

# named lists
l <- list(x = 2, y = 4)
l
#> $x
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] 4
c <- "{\"x\":3,\"y\":5}"
c
#> [1] "{\"x\":3,\"y\":5}"

toJSON(l, auto_unbox = TRUE)
#> {"x":2,"y":4}
fromJSON(c, simplifyVector = TRUE)
#> $x
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] 5

# vector without names
toJSON(c(1,2,3), auto_unbox = TRUE)
#> [1,2,3]
fromJSON("[4,5,6]", simplifyVector = TRUE)
#> [1] 4 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The `toJSON` function is great thanks! so just in addition then (pardon the pun), how would I create the addition function in a way that I can call the arguments from the rest API as we have expressed above in JSON format?

Comment: For example if I deploy that addition model in R, writing the arguments in JSON format for the rest API doesnt make sense because they dont have names

Comment: @M00NKNIGHT I revised my answer.